# Via API, zoom the pdf file make it be self-adaption to fit the web page?

Tags: pdf, zooming, pdfbox

A PDF file is embed on the web page, but when I scale the size of this web page, the PDF file will not fit the web page, so the PDF looks wierd. Can I use API, such as PDFBox, to sovle it?